# Python: Converting data into a table

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am relatively new to Python and I have the below script to obtain some data - but I'm not able to convert this to a format which I can consume since currently this is coming as a string. Can you please help?

Script:

```
request_url = 'https://abcd.com/'
kerberos_auth=HTTPKerberosAuth(mutual_authentication=OPTIONAL)
response=requests.get(request_url, auth=kerberos_auth).json()
data = pd.DataFrame(response)
print(data)
```

For this I get the below output:

```
0 {u'price': 1.0, u'cash': 100, u'currencyNo': 17, u'Name': u'Alpha'}
1 {u'price': 1.5, u'cash': 100, u'currencyNo': 16, u'Name': u'Beta'}
```

I want to convert the below data possibly for further filtering and stuff. Can someone help me how I can convert this to a table and into a format which I can later save to excel?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: What is `print (response)` ?

Comment: The response returned by `requests.get()` has a complex structure. You have to be more specific about what you want to convert to a table. If, for example, you expect the response to contain a JSON data, you can get it with `response.json()`. Look at the `requests` doc to see what are the other methods availabel for a response object.

Comment: jezrael - the output is similar to the above except they come as a list [{u'price': 1.0, u'cash': 100, u'currencyNo': 17, u'Name': u'Alpha'} ....

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting this response is that the data you request are unicode encoded.  Each data entry needs to be encoded to utf with:

```
dataentry.encode('utf-8')
```

After that you can use pd.DataFrame() again to get your table.